# DS3231 ESP32 I2C problem?

Tags: i2c, rtc, ds3231

I've got a new board prototype with an ESP32-S3 and a [BME688](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bme688-ds000.pdf) and and [DS3231](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/DS3231.pdf) on the same I2C bus (using pins 48=SDA and 47=SCL). I run the Examples => Wire => WireScan example making the necessary modification for my I2C pins `Wire.begin(48, 47)` instead of just `Wire.begin()`. I have 2.2kOhm pull-ups on SCL and SDA lines. When the scan runs it shows:

```
Scanning for I2C devices ...
Error 5 at address 0x68
I2C device found at address 0x77
```

I'm not sure what that means. I captured what's going on with a Saleae Logic and here's what it interprets.

Before encountering 0x68
[image]

After encoutering 0x68 (after a little while)/
[image]

I have the full Logic capture, available from Drive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dGaJIp1-HOAnOyPEOl-tCf-z59NZNlBi/view?usp=drive_link).

FWIW, I can't get the Examples => RTCLib => ds3231 example to work either. It just outputs "Couldn't find RTC". But obviously *something* is happening when I try and hit address 0x68... Also incidentally, the BME688 example ostensibly seems to work as intended.

What's going on here? My next stop is going to be an to pull out my oscilloscope, but I don't have one handy right now.

**UPDATE #1 [30 Sep 2023 21:09:08]**

OK, the oscilloscope shows something decidely not digital happening when 0x68 is addressed for writing.

[image]
[image]

What is this? Where do I go next for more help or what else do I try next?

**UPDATE #2 [1 Oct 2023 13:59:44]**

Here are the relevant schematic excerpts:
[image]
[image]

Aaaaand there's the problem, it looks like Ground is not connected.

Comment: What does the manual say what "Error 5" means? Also the logic capture is flawed likely because high enough sampling rate was not used and SDA&SCL edge happened at the same exact time and that's undefined what it means on an I2C bus. Or the logic analyzer decoding is just not working properly after some unexpected event. Sure the waveforms are not correct but there is something happening. What's the SCL frequency?

Comment: @Justme I've added an updated Oscilloscope trace and I can confirm that the I2C clock is 100kHz (10us period)

Comment: which one of the ESP32-S3 boards do have?

Comment: Is the RTC power supply OK? Are the MCU pins set to open-drain mode? Do you know what the Wire library does? Why are all interesting info such as voltage and time scale missing from scope photos? Can you add the schematics?

Comment: @Rodo Its a new design of my own making

Comment: @JustMe it's 2V/div for both traces and the time scale is 50us/div. Happy to add schematics later, but the BME688 on the same bus seems to work fine. I think the Wire library just binds the designated pins to the appropriate I2C controller.

Comment: @Justme post an answer if you want credit, since you pointed me in the right direction, I made a silly / basic mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the power supply of the chip.

In fact, a few hours ago I looked at the scope diagram again and it also hit me, it's not the **supply** pin that should be checked but the **ground** pin - but I didn't ask another comment at that time.

The oscilloscope diagram shows that as soon as the address is sent and RTC starts to drive the SDA low to transmit out a low ACK bit, it is not at ground level but slightly higher level. And as soon as SCL rises, the SDA rises immediately along with it. So the RTC got ground only through the low SCL and IO pin protection diodes, and that is why the SDA low was only about a diode drop higher from the 0V and SCL level.

Answer (score 0):

The Ground pin of my DS3231 is disconnected in the schematic. This is the manifestation of that design error.